# Override Google+ profile picture for my contacts

Tags: contacts, google-plus, profiles, contact-photo

I have a contact with a Google+ account. Whenever I search her for Hangouts or call, I get the picture from her Google+ account.

It does not matter if I go to google.com/contacts and I set up a new image. I will still keep seeing their Google+ image.

Is there any way to override it?

Comment: Does this contact that you've saved, has an IM or email added in the field?? If so, it picks-ups the google account as default. I've just tried updating such a contact on my tab, synced it and synced back to my mobile which did change.

Comment: You mean if she wrote her own email in the G+ profile? Yes, she does. Why?

Comment: Okay! let me clear your query again. Are you syncing your google+ account contacts to your phone? and then trying to change it??

Comment: My contact is synched with G+, but I want to customize the image it shows.

Comment: Did you sync your contacts after updating the image in google.com/contacts page? If not please sync your contacts and see if the updated image is displayed in your contacts app.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on my phone, and this has worked now with 2 contacts with caveats described below:

**Please note: I'm verifying this with contacts that definitely have Google+ profiles and are synced to my Google account.**

1. Select the contact (either from within Hangouts or via the Contacts app)
2. Choose the Pencil Icon to `edit` the contact.
3. Add a new picture.
4. Delete any extraneous fields that include things like `Facebook link` or `Profile link` or `Google+ Profile`, or any field with any sort of web address link

Now, on a computer through a web browswer

5. Navigate to [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com) and find your contact
6. Edit the contact again, **again** removing any links to profiles and such
7. Save and exit

Upon returning to Hangouts (and Messenger, etc.) the contact pictures should be changed on your phone. **Strangely, this photo edit will only take place on the phone, and not on the Google Contacts website. Conversely, changes made on the website seem not to affect photos you've changed on your device.**

Comment: I tried to follow these directions. The "Delete any fields that include things like Facebook link or Profile link or Google+ Profile" part is vague so I'm not sure if I'm following this. Anyway, I can update a pic for my contact but I can't override the Google+ pic if they have a G+ profile. I tried creating a new contact but Google links it to the G+ profile by email address. Frustrating.

Comment: I awarded you my bounty. I think it works now. I deleted my contact and re-added it. I only entered a phone number and no email address. Now Google doesn't know how to link it to G+ profile. I'll test further but I think this is success.

Comment: But now I can't send a gmail to the contact. Google is so screwed up.